# a program that searches an array of integers for 10 numbers to find if their sum is equal to a given nb

Tags: c, algorithm

you are given an array a of 100 integers and an integer x and you need to make a program to find if there is 10 integers in it where their sum is equal to x

my approach is by taking an example of how to find 3 integers with their sum equal to x :

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
for(j=i+1;j<100;j++)
   for(k=j+1;j<100;j++)
      if(a[i]+a[j]+a[k]==x) {found=1;break;}
if(found==1) 
printf("+ve result\n"); 
else printf("-ve result\n");
```

the problem is that if we want to apply this method to find 10 numbers whose as sumequals x, then it would be very large IF WE MAKE IT BY METHOD OF NESTED LOOPS as written here, so anyone has ideas about how to implement this code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: that didn't give me an answer

Comment: Cartesian product, if you don't mind exponential run time.

Comment: can you explain more @kevin what do you mean by cartesian product for this problem

Comment: @kevin: the Cartesian product is precisely what the OP describes as the method of nested loops.

Comment: What is the range of the values in the array a ? What is the range of x ?

Comment: Oops, perhaps I misinterpreted the post. When he said "then it would be very large if we make it by method of nested loops", I thought he meant "it would take many lines of code to write all those `for`s" rather than "it would take a long time to execute". If he means the former, replacing the loops with a single iterator over the cartesian product would be a valid solution.

Comment: i know that we can make it using 10 nested for loops but suppose i want to make it in a more ffective way thats what i am asking about

Comment: @YvesDaoust  the range of x is -100000<=x<=100000 and the array is of 100 integers size and its all filled(no empty slots)

Comment: "integers size": do you mean full range of (32 bits) ints ?

Comment: i mean we define the array by long a[100]; and x by long x
and you can also define them as int
the problem is just to find the code and these details are not important to me

Comment: @HYM: you are wrong to believe that these "details" are unimportant. They can make the difference between easy and forever intractable.

Comment: youre right but im only giving you the option to choose
ok take them as: int x,a[100];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the program would be very large. Actually, it would be less than twenty lines, which most people would call "tiny".

The problem is the execution time. You would calculate about 20 trillion different sums. Here is a hint: Since you calculate 20 trillion sums, you would expect that most of them give the same result. So how would avoid calculating numbers that are most of the time the same anyway?

I would define the set S (i, j, x) = { Set of integers 0 ≤ k ≤ x where k is the sum of at most i of the first j of your integers }. You have a solution if S (10, 100, x) contains the number x. S (0, j, x) is the set containing the number 0. All the other sets for i ≤ 10 and j ≤ 100 are trivial to calculate.

I assume you are supposed to find numbers at different indices. If that is not a requirement, it's a bit simpler; you only need to find sets that are sums of up to i numbers.

Comment: yes they must have different indeces ,but can you explain a little more?(i know you gave a hint but i am still confused about this so if you can give a pseudo-code or another hint)

Comment: and its true that the problem is in execution time

Comment: can you explain more @gnasher729 ?